Error citing a webpage in BibTex
I am citing a webpage in Bibtex. When I cite the webpage in the text, it appears two times in the PDF (see image below). I am citing using \cite{WCD}.
This is the code I am writing in Bibtex:
@misc{WCD,
    author = {WCD},
  title = {World Cities Database},
  howpublished = {\url{https://simplemaps.com/data/world-cities}},
  note = {Accessed: 2023-12-14}
}

And this is the bibligraphy style I am using.
\bibliographystyle{chicago}
\bibliography{Bibliography/Bibliography}

Note: This is just happening citing the websites. When I cite a paper or an article everything goes well, so I am very confused.
I have attached an image of what I mean by appearing two times in the PDF:


Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

If you are using LaTeX, considering using the biblatex-chicago package.
